# What is the difference between C++, Java and JavaScript exception handling?

Tags: java, javascript, c++, exception

They are very different kind of languages and the way they handle exceptions might be rather different.. How is exception handling implemented and what are the implementation difference within these languages?

I am asking this question also because I noticed that C++ exception handling seems to be very slow compared to the JavaScript version.

Comment: C++ — on which platform and which compiler?

Comment: I realized only after answering, do you mean by implementation the low-level details such as how Java constructs stacktraces and tracks the path of failure or something more high-level to which my answer is aimed to answer?

Comment: How could C++ exception handling possibly be slower than JavaScript?

With what browser, on what platform, running what code, compared to what compiler, on what platform, compiling what code?

Comment: @DeadMG C++ exceptions are often several orders of magnitude more costly than normal function returns; in JavaScript (at least before JIT, I'm not so sure now) the difference between the two is a lot less.

Comment: How many exceptions do you plan on throwing?  They're supposed to be *exceptional* cases.  Forgive me for being blunt, but why would you care how fast it is?

Comment: @KennyTM, on gcc, linux, but is there that much of a difference between C++ implementations? I am just wondering of the basic principles behind them to understand the differences between the languages.
@Kristo I just saw an horrifying code in Javascript, try-catch in a big loop and it seemed "faster" than I thought whereas in my mind, doing that in C++ is not even conceivable. Hence my asking, and I care because I am curious.

Comment: @Pete Kirkham: More expensive (maybe) orders of magnitude I find that an incredible statement to make without a reference.

Comment: @Dpp: It is quite possible to do. But most experienced C++ programmers would not do it as it smacks of inappropriate use. Faster than you though is a bit subjective and how did you compare that to an equivalent to a C++ version.

Comment: I guessed that interpreted language handle exceptions differently than with a compiled one. Do you guys say it is supposedly the same speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most detailed answer I found regarding Exception handling and performance/implementation is on this page:
http://lazarenko.me/tips-and-tricks/c-exception-handling-and-performance

Answer (score 1):

I know just the basics of C++ exception handling but as far as I can see, Java has excplicit `Object`-based hierarchy for exceptions ([`Throwable`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html), [`Exception`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html), [`RuntimeException`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html), [`Error`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html)) while in C++ you can do

```
try
{
     throw 1337;
}
catch (int i)
{
    // i == 1337
}
```

This of course reflects to the design of your class structures and general exception handling policies etc.

Other difference introduced by this seemingly minor difference is that C++ really only has what would be known as Runtime Exceptions in Java world, which means that you can throw anything at any time without explicitly writing code to handle the throw pseudo-exception (*I'm not willing to call `int` or any other primitive type an exception, they're just possibly exceptional values*).

Lastly, due to their nature when compared to Java's exceptions C++ exceptions don't *by default* contain anything comparable to Java's stacktraces.

Comment: It is recommended though in C++ to use classes that derive from std::exception

Comment: in JavaScript too, you can throw anything (besides the pre-defined Error objects). it’s just a question, how useful that is.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about how it internally generates these exceptions, then it's a pretty complex issue.

One approach (that I think C++ and Java use, I dont know about Javascript), is to maintain a stack of error handlers. When an exception is thrown, the the top entry is popped off the stack and handles the exception appropriately or pops another entry from the stack if it can't handle it (such as it received a NullPointerException when the top handler is a OutOfBoundException).

Comment: This strategy (a handler stack) is not used by any Java implementation that I've heard of.